# How do i import an sql file into an aurora serverless

Tags: mysql, sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-aurora-serverless

I have an sql file of a database i want to import into an aurora serverless database on aws.

I have enabled the data point api and can use the query editor.

I'm having issues trying to import the content of the sql file via the query editor and need help doing this.

If there's any other way i can also achieve this, I'll appreciate the help with that information as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dump of your data using the mysqldump utility, and then import that data into an existing Amazon Aurora MySQL DB cluster. For details, see Migrating from MySQL to Amazon Aurora by using mysqldump.

Here is the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.html#AuroraMySQL.Migrating.ExtMySQL.mysqldump